# Using histogram info in scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to color scatter plot markers based on histogram bins into which given value has been placed?
Having following example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1],
    'price': [12, 9, 2, 1, 10]})
```

I can print histogram with `hist = df.hist(bins=3, column='price')` as well as scatter plot with `df.scatter.plot(x='length', y='width')`.

But I cannot figure out a way to combine both of those instructions. What I'd expect to see is have 3 colors on scatter plot and colors will be assigned based on bin where give value fits.
Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram is just taking the range of values, and splitting it into equal size bins.

You can do this by using [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to assign points into specific bins:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1],
    'price': [12, 9, 2, 1, 10]
})
df['price'] = pd.cut(df['price'], bins=3)
df.plot.scatter(x='length', y='width', c='price', colormap='viridis')
```

Example output:

[image: binned scatterplot]

Answer (score 3):

The following approach first creates a colormap with 3 colors, and uses the price column to define the color. The scatter plot will add a colorbar indicating the relation between the colors and the prices.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd`
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1],
    'price': [12, 9, 2, 1, 10]})
num_colors = 3
cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow', num_colors)
df.plot.scatter(x='length', y='width', c='price', cmap=cmap)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot colored via third column]

PS: If you want to indicate the price borders, you can add these as colorbar ticks:

```py
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='length', y='width', c='price', cmap=cmap)
ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(df['price'].min(), df['price'].max(), num_colors + 1))
```

[image: showing the colorbar bins]